# Visual Studio 2010 will not install, fails to correctly detect Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2010

Trying to install from a disc image obtained through the [MSDNAA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSDNAA) (an Ultimate x86 DVD), and the installer adamantly insists I'm running a antiquated OS (it is, in fact, Windows 7 x64). I tried restarting the system and burning a physical disc to no avail. Even ran it in XP compatibility mode, for kicks (no dice). Weird!

Has anyone else seen this before? Or even better, have a solution?

Here's the error I'm getting - searching Google and Bing for the text hasn't turned up anything of worth yet.

[image]

***Edit*** Just an update--I reinstalled Windows 7 as well as grabbing Service Pack 1, and I'm now getting a different error when trying to install VS2010 on this clean install. Here's a snippet of the log. As best I can tell, the first error, followed by the long list of things that were not installed, are repeated three times:

```
[05/30/11,22:04:01] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64-bit Prerequisites (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:04:01] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
```

(more lines like this follow)

```
[05/30/11,22:16:08] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification.
[05/30/11,22:16:08] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[05/30/11,22:16:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
[05/30/11,22:16:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:16:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:16:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:16:08] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
```

(more lines like this)

```
[05/30/11,22:17:37] Microsoft Application Error Reporting: [2] CMsiComponent::Install() expects the setup file for Microsoft Application Error Reporting, but the file failed verification.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467259.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Application Error Reporting is not installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 9.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x86) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft .NET Framework 4 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 64-bit Prerequisites (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual F# 2.0 Runtime was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio Macro Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates TFS Object Model (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Web Deployment Tool (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Silverlight 3 SDK was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Crystal Reports templates for Visual Studio 2010 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x86) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Visual Studio 2010 Tools for SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Services for ADO.NET v2.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Sync Framework SDK v1.0 (x64) ENU was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates VC 10.0 Designtime (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 IntelliTrace (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Publishing Wizard 1.4 was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64) was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools was not attempted to be installed.
[05/30/11,22:17:37] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Help Viewer 1.0 x64 was not attempted to be installed.
```

Perhaps the disc image was corrupted in transit?

Comment: Have you run it as Administrator?

Comment: Yes, naturally.